# Recursively perform command on files

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to perform run a command in all C files within a folder and subfolders but I'm stuck because one of the folders has a space and I an error like this:

> Failed to load (D:\Code\Atmel) Failed to load (Studio\7.0\ADC_ADC_EXAMPLE1\ADC_ADC_EXAMPLE1\src\ASF\sam\utils\s
>   yscalls\gcc\syscalls.c)

```
for /R %%s in (*.c) do (
COMMAND
)
```

Comment: Your `COMMAND` probably mentions `%%s` without quotes. Just put it in quotes – `"%%s"` – wherever you use it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That COMMAND is in fact this: 
C:\utils\UniversalIndentGUI_win32\indenters\uncrustify.exe -c uncrustify.cfg -l C --replace %%s > UncrustOutput.txt

Comment: Running with `"%%s"` returns "in was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Ups, yes @DodgyCodeException you're right! having the `%%s` in that command solved it! Thanks for that!